# How to Increase the Vertical Gap Induced by the Linebreak Command on an Ad Hoc Basis?

Tags: line-breaking, vertical-spacing, gap, custom

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.25in]{geometry}
\textwidth=4in \textheight=3.50in 

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent{\textbf{\textit{Looking to Increase the Linebreak Gap on an\linebreak Ad Hoc Basis}}}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I increase the vertical gap of the `linebreak` command so that (in this case) "Ad Hoc Basis" appears, say, 10pt beneath its current position. Thank you.

*Remark:* I thought, perhaps, something like `\linebreak[10pt]` might work; but, although it does not give an error, the `[10pt]` portion of the hypothetical command has no effect on the output.

Comment: `\linebreak` has an optional argument that takes 0-4 for the strength of the penalty, `[10pt]` parses at 10 which acts like the maximum 4, and leaves `pt`  in the unused `0` case.  if you used `[0pt]` you would get an error as it would act like 0 but then `pt\z@` isn't a valid numeric penalty value

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not know that. Thank you for the "technical support" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

such a construct should almost never appear in a document but

`\vspace{10pt}\linebreak`

[image]

Comment: Ah! Many thanks! But what (I'm almost afraid to ask) is wrong with such a construct?

Comment: you should almost never need `\linebreak` in a document (I don't think I have ever used it in over 30 years of latex use) and only a very small fraction of those uses should have a vertical space attached. @DDS

Comment: I see. Thanks again.